# How to store the user activity in smart contract or can I use smart contract to track all user activity on my site?

Tags: solidity, truffle-contract, .net

New to blockchain and smart contracts. Been doing research and I am having a CRUD application in SQL Server.

I want to use ethereum private blockchain to record all the user activity. Can I use for that purpose?

Comment: I think the question to ask now is, why do you want to use blockchain for user tracking ?

Comment: Yes, this is easily possible, but why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: My customer is having a portal which is just having a Servay Service with set of questions and he wants to track everything in blockchain what user have selected as an answer and the overall report in blockchain. So the questions is if i store everything in the blockchain is it really a good practice to do so and how can i achieve the perofrmance over long period of time as it will be having many more users in the future and data size in blockchain will increase rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

Not to say that it would be a very *good* reason to create a private blockchain, but yes, you could do that. You can write a smart contract with a function that takes whatever parameters you want and store data in the contract. You can then have functions that do queries on the data you store or just read the data as is.

Comment: My customer is having a portal which is just having a Servay Service with set of questions and he wants to track everything in blockchain what user have selected as an answer and the overall report in blockchain. So the questions is if i store everything in the blockchain is it really a good practice to do so and how can i achieve the perofrmance over long period of time as it will be having many more users in the future and data size in blockchain will increase rapidly.